# Is it possible to get a segmentation error by accessing allocated, but uninitialized data in old regular c? I can't see how

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault, pthreads

Should be a straightforward question I think, but just in case context helps I'll add some info below:

I was developing a module for someone else and the module crashed via a segmentation error that occurred during a  pthread_mutex_unlock(lock); call. I do not implement pthreads in my code at all, and the calling function is theoretically impossible to create a segmentation error with from what I can see:

```
bool IsValidTeam(Team4v4Data* td)//pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex* lock) segfaulted here on the log
{
    if (!td)
        return false;
    else if (strncmp (td->captain, "INVALID_CAPTAIN", NAMESIZE) == 0)
        return false;

    //we checked for a null pointer and for the struct w/name  that should be passed during an error,
    //"INVALID_CAPTAIN", as the name, could get a non-null bad pointer but calling function 
    //should handle that in 100% of cases

    //if we did receive bad data though, we never got to the end of this function to the caller
    return true;
}
```

The calling function should never return anything other than valid data for the IsValidTeam call though:

```
Team4v4Data* GetCaptainsTeam(Player* p)
{
    MyArenaData* mad = P_ARENA_DATA(arena4v4, arenaKey); //not mine and always works
    
    FOR_EACH_TEAM(t)//#defined as: for (int t = 0; t < MAXTEAMS; t++)
    {
        if (strncmp(mad->team[t].captain, p->name, NAMESIZE) == 0)
        {
            return &mad->team[t];
        }
    }
    //if we got here, none of the teams matched the players name
    //possible returns: a valid team object that matches the players name,
    //or this invalid team object containing td->captain is "INVALID_CAPTAIN"        
    return &mad->INVALID_TEAM;
}
```

And the caller's caller:

```
void Cready(Player* p, params* par, Target* targ, Arena* arena)//unsure of parameters, should be right
{
    Team4v4Data* td = GetCaptainsTeam(p);
    if (!IsValidTeam(td))//segmentation fault here
    {
        td->ready = true;
    }
    //else
        //notify players an error occurred and re-initialize/return the module 
        //to prevent further ones
    
    //do some processing, never got here
}
```

And rough outline of the structs:

```
typedef struct MyArenaData
{
    Team4v4Data team[MAXTEAMS];
    Team4v4Data INVALID_TEAM;//used for error checking in function returns instead of null pointer
//other random bools and data
} MyArenaData;

typedef struct Team4v4Data
{
    char captain[20];//normally initialized to "", but failed to initialize due to bug
    Player4v4Data slots[MAXPLAYERS];//has its own initializers, not used during our error though

//other random bools and data
} Team4v4Data;

typedef struct Player4v4Data
{
    char name[20];//normally initialized to "", but failed to initialize due to bug
    //other player stats
}
```

So when the error occurred, *we discovered the data in the locations for the team and arena data was uninitialized due to a mislabeled function*.
However, I don't think it is possible that the data being accessed could cause a segmentation error because even if not initialized, *it should still be the "correct" memory location for that data* - any read or write operations may cause "unintended behavior", but the program should not ever be going past its buffer or reading/writing random memory locations because the pointers should always point to a valid data area, by design.

My question is: Am I correct in this thinking? Is it possible this seg fault originated from my code, or is it "must be something else" in the module handler because of the safety mechanisms in place being unable to access outside memory in this instance?

Also, any suggestions about null pointer safety or better data checking ideas are welcome. Thanks for looking.

EDIT: crash log:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__pthread_mutex_unlock_usercnt (mutex=0xffffffff, decr=1) at pthread_mutex_unlock.c:41 41      pthread_mutex_unlock.c: No such file
or directory. (gdb) bt
#0  __pthread_mutex_unlock_usercnt (mutex=0xffffffff, decr=1) at pthread_mutex_unlock.c:41
#1  0xf3a0465a in Cready (command=0xffffce3c "ready", params=0x82b3aa8 "\003", p=0xffffd084, target=0x0) at 4v4mod/4v4mod.c:327
#2  0x0807b5bf in run_commands (text=0x8380adf "", p=0x82b3aa8, target=0xffffd084, sound=0) at core/chat.c:366
#3  0x0807b9fd in handle_pub (p=0x82b3aa8, msg=0x8380ad9 "?ready", ismacro=0, isallcmd=0, sound=0) at core/chat.c:448
#4  0x0807c5c9 in PChat (p=0x82b3aa8, pkt=0x8380ad4 "\006\002", len=12) at core/chat.c:667

(gdb) frame 1
#1  0xf3a0465a in Cready (command=0xffffce3c "ready", params=0x82b3aa8 "\003", p=0xffffd084, target=0x0) at 4v4mod/4v4mod.c:327 327          
if (!IsValidTeam(td)) //player was not a captain, do nothing (gdb)
info locals td = 0xffffffff mad = 0xdfd7c300 (gdb) info args command =
0xffffce3c "ready" params = 0x82b3aa8 "\003" p = 0xffffd084 target =
0x0
```

Comment: Just a maybe ... the allocation of memory is "lazy" ie, there is only real memory once you write to it ... so reading from uninitialized memory (even though the address was correctly obtained from `malloc()`) may cause problems. I think this is also why `void *p = malloc(16*GIGA); free(p);` works on my 4G machine .

Comment: oh, is that invalid team initialized to "" ? its going to break the strncmp..

Comment: What does valgrind or address sanitizer say?

Comment: The `IsValidTeam` can't segfault on `pthread_mutex_lock` because it's _not_ doing one. It _could_ segfault if `td` was invalid [you already check for null]. It could fault if `td->captain` was null or invalid. But, _if_ you've really getting `pthread_mutex_lock` to segfault, that's [probably] because something is running over a limit and the lock data is being corrupted. You are correct that if you do a `malloc` [and get back a non-null pointer], you can use that pointer (i.e. the memory _is_ "there"). Usual caveats about using unitialized values in that area apply.

Comment: But, I'd say that the unlock related segfault is happening elsewhere and only seems to occur in your function. Compile with `-g` and without `-O` to be sure, so `gdb` reports correctly. `GetCaptainsTeam` seem more suspect to me. `malloc` et. al. _do_ use mutexes [even in single thread--sort of, there is some linker trickery to make them dummies if _not_ linked with `-lpthread`]. So, what is `MyArenaData mad -> GET_ARENA_DATA(arena4v4);//not mine and always works` (i.e. `->` syntax error) but _what_ is `GET_ARENA_DATA`? It looks like a `malloc` wrapper

Comment: From your `gdb` traceback, it is failing in `Cready`. But, I suspect that it's in `GetCaptainsTeam` but, with optimization, the call to the latter is being inlined.

Comment: @secretsquirrel thanks, didn't know that. changed my checks to an #define INVALID_NAME

Comment: @CraigEstey
Craig:
I wrote this from work, but I updated the OP to include the correct line. So here's the normal line (so you dont have to find it up there:

MyArenaData* mad = P_ARENA_DATA(arena4v4, arenaKey);
And the definition:
/** Use this to access per-arena data.
 * param a an arena pointer
 * param mykey a key to per-arena data obtained from
 * Iarenaman::AllocateArenaData.
 */
#define P_ARENA_DATA(a, mykey) ((void*)((a)->arenaextradata+mykey))
So it's just a macro. But it's failing on UNLOCK, not on LOCK

Comment: Note that the [failing] mutex address is `FFFFFFFF`, so probably not valid [and, if 32 bit mode, a portion probably wraps to 0, and the first page is mapped no access to catch these errors]. Based on the macro text you posted, I'd look at `a`, `arenaextradata`, and `mykey` values. At a guess, one or more is zero (e.g. `arenaextradata`) and one might be -1 (e.g. `mykey`). With optimization off, I'd break on the start and single step. So, from the caller of the macro, `arena4v4` could be null, but, more likely, `arena4v4->arenaextradata` is, and `arenaKey` is -1

Comment: Oh ok, yeah that clearly isn't my calling code then - that stuff is already in the server. I didn't notice that when I looked, thanks